# ¿Cómo puedo exportar un excel con una enorme cantidad de datos de forma "paginada" con Spout/PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

Tengo una enorme cantidad de datos obtenidos de base de datos a los cuáles luego de ser obtenidos se le aplican muchos cálculos y, por último, se utiliza PHP Excel para generar el Xslx.

Estoy considerando cambiar la librería PHP Excel por Spout debido al uso exponencial de memoria que usa el primero a medida que la cantidad de columnas y filas aumentan.

He creado un método que obtiene los datos de 100 en 100, es decir, 100 registros. La idea es que para los primeros 100 registros se cree el excel y para los sucesivos 100 registros se modifique ese excel previamente creado. ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Actualmente tengo un método que crea el excel:

```
$obj = new PHPExcel();
$obj->removeSheetByIndex(0);
```

Luego se invoca al método que hace la primera hoja y la retorna. Esta primera hoja se asigna al excel:

```
$objHoja = $this->X->crear_excel($data);
$hoja= $objHoja->getSheet(0);
$obj->addExternalSheet($hoja);
```

Donde `$data` contiene absolutamente todo (pesa mucho en memoria RAM).
La idea es llamar a `crear_excel` con `$data` que contenga únicamente los primeros 100, y luego crear un `editar_excel` pero esto no sé cómo hacerlo. ¿Debería pasarle el `$objHoja` y cómo se cuál es la última línea? (teniendo en cuenta que hay columnas, etc).